# Retrieve @XmlEnumValue annotation attribute value in Jaxb converted Enum Class

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb, annotations

```
@XmlType(name = "WeekEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum WeekEnum implements Serializable {

    MONDAY("Monday"),

    @XmlEnumValue("SUNDAY.ON")
    SUNDAY("Sunday")

    private final String value;

    WeekEnum(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static WeekEnum fromValue(String v) {
        for (WeekEnum c: WeekEnum.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
}
```

I have an Enum class WeekEnum which is a Jaxb class.

`WeekEnum day = WeekEnum.SUNDAY;`

To get the value "**Sunday**" from Enum **day** we write **day.value();**

To get the value "**SUNDAY**" from Enum **day** we write **day.name();**

How do we get the value "**SUNDAY.ON**" from Eum **day** ??

If I have the value "**Sunday**" how do we get corresponding "**SUNDAY.ON**" ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store it in separate variable similar to value.

```
@XmlType(name = "WeekEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum WeekEnum implements Serializable {

MONDAY("Monday"),

@XmlEnumValue("SUNDAY.ON")
SUNDAY("Sunday", "SUNDAY.ON")

private final String value;
private final String xmlValue;

WeekEnum(String v) {
    value = v;
}
WeekEnum(String v, String xmlValue){
   this(v);
   this.xmlValue = xmlValue;
}

public String value() {
    return value;
}

public String getXmlValue() {
    return xmlValue;
}

public static WeekEnum fromValue(String v) {
    for (WeekEnum c: WeekEnum.values()) {
        if (c.value.equals(v)) {
            return c;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
}
}
```

Comment: Problem is we dont have control over Enum, Value or annotation. Its something we dont have access to. Its a third party Jaxb. Maximum we can add methods to the Enum Class. Is there any way we can get the required annotation value using Java core methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of the enum called week, you can do the following

```
week.getClass().getField(week.name()).getAnnotation(XmlEnumValue.class).value()
```